# Why typescript cannot import type user from firebase?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

I just created a new project and started to import some code, regarding firebase.
I've installed a bunch of firebase libraries: `firebase`, `@angular/fire`, `@ngxs-labs/firestore-plugin`.

I've the following authGuard:

```
import { User } from 'firebase';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router, CanActivate, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap,  } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}
  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): boolean | UrlTree | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> {
    return this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
      switchMap<User, Observable<boolean>>((user, index) => {
        if (!user) {
          this.router.navigate(['/auth/signin']);
          return of(false);
        }

        return of(true);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

but here, like at some other places for the same class, I get this error when I try to compile or to serve:

```
ERROR in src/app/auth/auth.guard.ts:1:10 - error TS2614: Module '"../../../node_modules/firebase"' has no exported member 'User'. Did you mean to use 'import User from "../../../node_modules/firebase"' instead?
```

So the suggestion is exactly the same as what is currently written. This is working in my other project, and the firebase package is definitely installed.

Any idea why it cannot find the reference? If I remove the import, VS Code propose me exactly the same thing.

Comment: can you share your package.json ?

Comment: does firebase come with it's own types? if not you may need to install them. `@types/firebase`